# Use kerberos authentication for git repo access in SQL Developer?

Tags: git, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, kerberos

Does Oracle SQL Developer offer any support to connect to git repositories using kerberos authentication?

My only option to connect to a git repo is kerberos, so if it doesn't, is there an Oracle SQL client that supports version control through git that *does* support kerberos authentication to git while allowing TNS-name based DB connections?

Comment: There is absolutely no connection between Git and any Oracle SQL client. Use Git Bash or TortoiseGit.

Comment: That's just patently untrue -- SQL Developer has a native Teams function and builtin git client